# Request spec only first context is success

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a request spec and I wanted to test CRUD.

The problem is whatever request I put first succeeds, but the rest that follows fail. (Meaning, in the case below, `GET` will succeed, but `POST` will fail. If
I switch the 2 context blocks, `POST` then succeeds, then `GET` fails).

> The failing test says the response is `401 Unauthorized`. I'm not sure if the `api_key` suddenly becomes invalid or something. Or it has something to do with the role I assigned it. (I assigned a system_admin role to the user to be able to CRUD via `cancancan`)

> The way that makes it all work is if I put all requests in one big `it` block (which I think is not good practice since it returns only 1 passing example, when in reality I have more than 1.)

I've also tried signing in my user again in each block but still the same thing happens.

I am very new to RSpec so any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much!

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "Departments", type: :request do

    user = FactoryBot.build(:user)
    role = FactoryBot.build(:role, name: "system_admin")
    user.add_role(role.name)

    headers = { "x-app-api-key" => user.api_key }

    before do
      sign_in user
    end
  
  describe "CRUD /v1/departments" do

    context "GET" do
      it "called get" do
        get api_departments_path, headers: headers
 
        expect(response.content_type).to eq("application/json; charset=utf-8")
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
      end
    end

    context "POST" do
      it "called post" do
        post api_departments_path, headers: headers, params: { name: "department" }

        expect(response.content_type).to eq("application/json; charset=utf-8")
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You should look at why the code is failing on controller part. Maybe look or disable a before_action that do auth and see where it is failing. Does your API key can only be used once?

Answer (score 0):

There are a LOT of problems with this spec. First off the bat is your use of local variables instead of `let/let!`:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "Departments", type: :request do
  user = FactoryBot.build(:user)
  role = FactoryBot.build(:role, name: "system_admin")
  user.add_role(role.name)
```

The problem with this is that these variables will be set when RSpec sets up the spec and not for each example. So provided you actually did insert the records into the database they will still be wiped after the first example is run and all the subsequent examples will fail.

So lets fix that problem:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "Departments", type: :request do
  let(:user) { FactoryBot.create(:user) } 
  let(:role) { FactoryBot.create(:role, name: "system_admin") } 
  before do
    user.add_role(role.name)
  end
```

`let` is evaluated once per example and then memoized.

Note the use of `create` instead of `build` which saves the record in the database so that it can actually be accessed from the controller.

Then there is the problem that these tests don't actually provide any value or describe the behavior of the application that you're testing besides testing the http response code.

Test your application - not your tests. If the failure message doesn't tell you anything about what part of the application doesn't work the test is near worthless.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "Departments", type: :request do

  let(:user) { FactoryBot.create(:user) } 
  let(:role) { FactoryBot.create(:role, name: "system_admin") } 
  let(:headers) do 
    { "x-app-api-key" => user.api_key }
  end
  let(:json) { response.parsed_body }

  before do
    user.add_role(role.name)
    sign_in user  
  end

  describe "GET /v1/departments" do
    let(:departments) { FactoryBot.create_list(:department, 5) }
    it "responds with a list of the departments" do
      get api_departments_path, headers: headers
      expect(response).to be_successful
      # @todo ensure the JSON response contains the expected departments
    end
  end
  
  describe "POST /v1/departments" do
    context "with invalid parameters" do
      let(:params) { { name: "" } } # this should just be an invalid or incomplete set of attributes

      it "doesn't create a department" do
        expect do
          post api_departments_path, headers: headers, params: params
        end.to_not change(Department, :count)
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:unprocessable_entity)
      end 
    end

    context "with valid parameters" do
      let(:params) { FactoryBot.attributes_for(:department) }

      it "creates a department" do
        expect do
          post api_departments_path, headers: headers, params: params
        end.to change(Department, :count).by(1)
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:created)
        # @todo test that either a JSON representation is returned 
        # or that the response contains a location header with the URI 
        # to the resource
      end 
    end
  end
end
```

Testing the content type is largely superflous as you set the content type in the defaults for an API app and testing the JSON responses would fail if its not returning `application/json`.

Comment: This code isn't intended to as a drop in fix. There are so many problems with the code in the question so the best I can do is to give you a nudge in the right direction.